# JS get element html and lowercase/hyphenate and add as class to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope the title makes sense, I am trying to get the HTML of an element in each     li element so e.g.

```
<li><a class="title">Free Stuff</a></li>
```

I am trying to get the html "Free Stuff" and lowercase that, remove the white space and add a hyphen then use that as the class name on the li, so the end result means the li will be

```
<li class="free-stuff">
```

I hope this makes sense. If you are wondering why I am using JS to do this its because I cant use php due to the nature of the wordpress plugin and not touching plugin core files for update purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('ul').children('li').each(function(i) {
     $(this).addClass($(this).children('a').text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-'));
});
```

Comment: It is useless to loop with `each()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```js
$('li').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
})
```

```css
.free-stuff {
  color: blue
}
.expensive-stuff {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="title">Free Stuff</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="title">Expensive Stuff</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned solutions do work in your case. However, if you have multiple white spaced words, you need a replaceAll, rather than replace.

Here is something you could do, if you have a need for replace multiple white spaces.

```js
$('li').addClass(function() {
  var regEx = new RegExp(/ /, "g");
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(regEx, "-");
})
```

```css
.free-stuff {
  color: blue;
}
.more-free-stuff {
  color: green;
}
.expensive-stuff {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="title">Free Stuff</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="title">More Free Stuff</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="title">Expensive Stuff</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```